# How can i equal div width to take container width in bootstrap grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 8 div in container and I want to divide equal with to the div to take with of container which class can do this for me in bootstap

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="col-md-"></div>
     <div class="col-md-"></div>
     <div class="col-md-"></div>
     <div class="col-md-"></div>
     <div class="col-md-"></div>
     <div class="col-md-"></div>
     <div class="col-md-"></div>
     <div class="col-md-"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem at all mate ^^

Comment: can it is possible in one div

Comment: It's hardly possible since 12 doesn't divide by 8, you can use offsets but it would create spaces between divs